# Virtualbox : 2-network card setup makes it impossible to reach the Internet

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 client installed on Vbox with 2 NICs : 1 in NAT (DHCP) and 1 as an internal network card, the latter with a manual IP, to try and communicate with a virtual Ubuntu server that I also created.

When only the first NIC is active, I can access the internet freely, even though a traceroute only returns asterisks.

If I activate the second one, the Internet is cut off and I have no idea how to solve it.

Here is the NIC configuration (enp0s3 is the "normal" NIC and enp0s8 the internal network NIC):

[image]

And here is my routing table:

[image]

There is also this 169.254.0.0/16 network that is present although I don't have any idea why...?

Here is my /etc/network/interfaces file:

[image]

Comment: Can you please edit your post, and add the output of (1) `nano /etc/network/interfaces` and (2) `nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf` to help you better.

Comment: There is no /etc/dhcpcd.conf, I will edit the post to show the interfaces file.